# OSX Big Sur Window UI turns purple when moved to desktop two

Tags: macos, big-sur

The UI on my Macbook Air M1 turns into purple beautifully when the window is moved to Desktop 2.

This does not seems to be the tinting feature of Big Sur, since the color turns to black again when moved back to desktop 1.

Does any one know what's going on?

My purple safari

[image]

My purple settings

[image]

Comment: This is specifically **Spaces** Desktop 2, as opposed to a different physical display?

Comment: Yes. The kind you can switch to by ctrl-left/right or a three fingers swipe. It is not on a different physical display.

Answer (score 12):

Same issue here. Filed a bug report to apple.
Specially XCode looks annoying .... but only when shown in fullscreen or on a second desktop. The main desktop is fine.

**I worked around it by:**

System Preferences -> General -> **DISABLE**: "Allow wallpaper tinting in windows"

Answer (score 1):

Same Issue. It seems Big Sur has an error **when creating the 2nd desktop**. It also turns white all the icons and text in the upper bar.

If you create 3 or more desktops, and move the window to any one except 2d it doesn't show a purple window. Even when you close the 2d desktop.

**Work around:**

1. Create 3 desktops
2. Move your window to the 3rd one
3. Delete 2d desktop

Answer (score 1):

Another fix that worked for me:

System Preferences --> Accessibility --> Display, check the "Reduce Transparency" box.

This will turn off transparency across all apps and all desktop spaces but it also fixed the purple tint on desktop two.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your second space has a purple background, and that is shining through the transparent windows.