# Changing hue of blacks/dark colors to a purple/red-ish tint on my Macbook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, display, apple-silicon

Why is it that sometimes, the hue of the blacks or dark colors on my Macbook, especially apps that are made by Apple like finder, the dock, the menu bar, change their hue randomly to a purple-ish color (as shown in the photos below). However, third-party apps like Microsoft Word, Opera GX, and etc., aren't affected by this.

I've tried changing a few things on the Display settings on System Preferences, it goes away for a while. But, it still keeps coming back randomly and quite frequently

Hope you guys can help, thanks!

[image]

Comment: Reminded me of this question - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/410416/osx-big-sur-window-ui-turns-purple-when-moved-to-desktop-two - but it has no answers

Comment: Perhaps something to do with transparency in the GUI?